# 2 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Tags: apt, 19.04

```
find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;
```

etc/apt/sources.list

```
 1  #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.04 _Disco Dingo_ - Release amd64 (20190416)]/ disco main restricted
 2  
 3  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
 4  # newer versions of the distribution.
 5  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
 6  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
 7  
 8  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
 9  ## distribution.
10  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
11  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
12  
13  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
14  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
15  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
16  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
17  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
18  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
19  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
20  
21  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
22  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
23  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
24  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
25  ## security team.
26  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
27  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
28  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
29  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
30  
31  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
32  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
33  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
34  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
35  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
36  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
37  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
38  
39  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
40  ## 'partner' repository.
41  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
42  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
43  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
44  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
45  
46  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
47  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
48  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
49  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
50  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse
51  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse
52  
53  # This system was installed using small removable media
54  # (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
55  # entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
56  # For information about how to configure apt package sources,
57  # see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

While I do t@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update

```
[sudo] password for t: 
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease            
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                   
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done           
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

All these are coming on Ubuntu 19.04 64 bit running in Vmware environment.
What should I do to resolve them?

Comment: Not sure but I think it is trying to update from the cdrom.  Check your 'software and updates' and uncheck cdrom at the bottom.  Did that myself some years ago.

Comment: If not cdrom, check internet from Vmware, and/or change download mirror.

Comment: There seems to be some problem in Ubuntu 19.04 networking itself it is connected with all default settings of Vmware workstation 15 , some times it is able to ping google.com and some times it is not able to ping I get following message `t@ubuntu:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
` while the host OS is constantly connected. I don't know how to change download mirror in GUI there was an option to download all updates from main server previously it was US repositories I changed that to main server.

Comment: Will be in 'software and updates' also.  Click on down arrow, where it says 'download from'.  Will give choice of different mirrors or can test them and show you best one.

Comment: Any chance of using virtualbox or are you lock in to vmware( too much data or something).  I can't help much with either, but maybe you can ask another question if vmware keeps giving you problem.

Comment: This problem has been solved , there was some problem the way in which Vmware made its default network. There were 3 options in networking of vmware I had choosen default NAT, Host Only, Custom :Specific virtual network vmnet0 I was using NAT and that was the default option I don't know why this problem arose in it, I choose Custome:Vmnet0 and things are working fine now in the virtual machine.